# How to create a website form field in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form where I'd like to be able to input a web address, like "google.com", into a form field, and be able to click on this link in the show view of the submitted form.

How can I accomplish this?

**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Website:</strong>
  <%= link_to @video.website, @video.website %>
</p>
```

Comment: is this URL field part of a larger model, or is it an entity in and of itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding will handle it like Jason Swett said.  If you are looking to put it in a link in show just do something like this:

```
  <%=link_to @link.name, "http://"+@link.url%>
```

If that doesn't work you could always do:

```
 <a href="http://<%= @link.url%>"><%=@link.name%></a>
```

Comment: I know about scaffolding...what I'm trying to do is to just make the google link clickable on the show page after it has been submitted. I added the code I currently have in the app above. Right now, every time I click on the link in the show form, it goes to: "http://localhost:3000/videos/google.com", so there's an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: @user14294966.  You probably don't have the http:// or https:// appended.  ```<a href="google.com">``` will go to a file called google.com and ```<a href="http://google.com">``` will go to the site.  Updating answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffolding will handle this for you. I recommend going through the Rails Guides, especially this one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

And more specifically, you can generate a model with an attribute called `url` like this:

```
rails generate scaffold Thing url:string
```

And then run your migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

You should end up with some views in `app/views/thing/` and a controller at `app/controllers/thing_controller.rb`. That should put you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model that has an attribute like `web_address`, you can do:

```
= text_field_tag, "web_address", ""
```

(using HAML syntax and tags for form_tag)

And then in your show you can do:

```
= link_to model.web_address, model.web_address
```

Which will make a link like: http://www.google.ca